# How many maps $\phi \colon \Bbb N \to \Bbb N \cup \{0\}$ are there?

Tags: functions

> How many maps $\phi \colon \Bbb N \to \Bbb N \cup \{0\}$ are there with the property that $\, \phi(ab)=\phi(a)+\phi(b), \forall a,b \in \Bbb N \cup \{0\}$ ?

The options are as follows :

> 1. None
> 2. finitely many
> 3. countably many
> 4. uncountably many

i tried i this way. Taking $a=b=1$ i got $\phi (1)=0$ so $\phi(x)=0$ is at least one map. But dont know how to deal with other options?

Comment: **Hint:** Once you choose $\phi(p)$ for every prime $p$, everything else is determined.

Comment: Could you please clarify $\phi$'s domain? You write that $\phi : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, but then you also imply that $\phi(0)$ is defined.

Comment: then there will be uncountable number of such maps? -@HenningMakholm

Comment: how many primes are there?

Comment: I think you'll need to answer Patrick's clarification request first.

Comment: yes $\phi (0)$ is defined but its not necessary to include ${0}$ in the domain. Is it?

Comment: i don't know i am right or not but for eg. let $f:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=x^{2}$. Here $f(-1)$ is defined but we have not taken the domain. Does it make statement wrong? -@HenningMakholm

Comment: But there are $\aleph_0$ choices for each element in the domain-@dm63

Comment: If $0$ is included in the domain then $\phi(k)=0$ for all $k\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$ is the only solution.